# I seem to be gettting an unknown provider error when I am trying to call the config provider in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I seem to be gettting an unknown provider error when I am trying to call the config provider

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicConfigProvider

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    // Turn off caching for demo simplicity's sake
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
    $ionicTabsConfig.type = '';
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style(standard);
    /*
    // Turn off back button text
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false);
    */




    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.activity', {
        url: '/activity',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/activity.html',
                controller: 'ActivityCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
                template: '<button id="fab-activity" class="button button-fab button-fab-top-right expanded button-energized-900 flap"><i class="icon ion-paper-airplane"></i></button>',
                controller: function ($timeout) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        document.getElementById('fab-activity').classList.toggle('on');
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing to add dependency of `$ionicTabsConfig` in your config block

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicTabsConfig, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    //... You config code remains as is


});
```

Comment: i missed that while posting. sorry...but still that problem occurs

Comment: I changed my code like this,so it's working now    
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 
  $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

    // the pet tab has its own child nav-view and history
    .state('tab.pet-index', {
      url: '/pets',
      views: {
        'pets-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/pet-index.html',
          controller: 'PetIndexCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
});

Comment: @MaheshMohanan basically you removed the dependency were not in use.. Glad to here that it fixed..you could accept the answer.if it does helped you.. :)